# How to get data from ajax GET query

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm doing a GET request using `$.ajax()`:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('#acsess').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://f4c0c1f3aa9a506c69b3b6642864b3590fb8f76f@504080.com/api/v1/services/categories',
      method: 'GET',
      beforeSend: function(req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "f4c0c1f3aa9a506c69b3b6642864b3590fb8f76f");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        jQuery.each(data, function (index, value) {
          // need to create divs with *icon and *title from data
        })
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("error");
      }
    })
  });
});
```

I got this in my console:
[image]

And I can't retrieve icon link and title text. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it helps me to resolve problem

`success: function(data) {
                var ololo = data.data;
                for (let i = 0; i < ololo.length; i++) {console.log(ololo[i].title);}
           }`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data (which seems to be an array) by `data[index].icon` and `data[index].title`.
If you need to access all the items, I recommend a simple loop:

```
success: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i++; i < data.length) {
        data[i].icon // it's here, what to do is up to you
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately when i'm trying do simple manipulation: `console.log(data[index].icon);`  , console shows me **Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined**

Comment: Substitute index with a number. I used the word index to represent a position in the array. Try data[0].icon

Comment: now it's return me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined`

Comment: Check what the ajax returned in that case.